# dump ruamel yaml - preserving the original structure

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I have this yaml file (`file_in.yaml`),

```
components: &base
  type1: 3  # sample comment
  type2: 0x353
  type3: 1.2.3.4
  type4: "bla"
  schemas:
    description: 'ex1' # this is comment
    description: 'ex2'

test2:
  <<: *base
  type4: 4555  # under the sea :)

yellow: &yellow
  bla: 1

collor: &yellow
  bla: 2

paint:
  color: *yellow

slot_si_value_t: &bla1
    desc: hav slot 2
    slot_number: 2 #SI_SLOT_2
    inst_max: 4

slot_si_value_t: &bla2
    desc: hav slot 4
    slot_number: 4 #SI_SLOT_4
    inst_max: 4

slot:
  - slot_si_value: *bla1
  - slot_si_value: *bla2
```

I load it with this code snippet, and dump it into another file.

```
import ruamel.yaml

ryaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
ryaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
ryaml.preserve_quotes = True

with open("file_in.yaml") as si_file:
    si_data = ryaml.load(si_file)

with open("file_out.yaml", "w") as fp:
    ryaml.dump(si_data, fp)
```

the `file_out.yaml` looks like this,

```
components: &base
  type1: 3  # sample comment
  type2: 0x353
  type3: 1.2.3.4
  type4: "bla"
  schemas:
    description: 'ex1' # this is comment

test2:
  <<: *base
  type4: 4555  # under the sea :)

yellow:
  bla: 1

collor: &yellow
  bla: 2

paint:
  color: *yellow

slot_si_value_t: &bla1
  desc: hav slot 2
  slot_number: 2   #SI_SLOT_2
  inst_max: 4

slot:
- slot_si_value: *bla1
- slot_si_value:
    desc: hav slot 4
    slot_number: 4 #SI_SLOT_4
    inst_max: 4
```

I can see that the comments, quotes, hex values and the order are preserved, however the structure of the yaml is changed. Is there any ways to instruct ruamel to dump the exact format?

here is a side-by-side comparison,

[image]

Comment: How did you create this invalid YAML input? By hand or with a program (which one)?

Comment: @Anthon By program. We have geniuses who could generate such yaml files and cause headache for us.

Comment: It is possible to generate a different key if you encounter one that is already in (e.g `description_d0`, `description_d1`, etc). Requires a bit more code but is doable, post a new question if you want me to look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve all anchors by changing the `.yaml_set_anchor` method of the `CommentedBase`. For
historical reasons this is currently only done for scalar values that are anchored (i.e. it is inconsistent).

Having duplicate keys in your YAML mappings however makes the document invalid, because keys have to be unique
according to the YAML [specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#mapping). In order
to allow *loading* of these faulty documents `ruamel.yaml` allows you to load such broken
documents by setting `.allow_duplicate_keys`, **but it doesn't support writing such incorrect documents**
and *disregards further occurrences of the same key* in a mapping (during loading, so you cannot access the values for those keys, unless the are anchored **and** aliased somewhere else).

That is why you "lose" the `description: 'ext2'` under key `schemas`, including the following
empty line (which is part of that entries "comment")

The second occurrence of `slot_si_value_t` in the root mapping causes more problems. Because
it is not preserved, the `&bla2` anchored mapping exists only once in the loaded
data and gets dumped (with an anchor because the `.yaml_set_anchor` change), within
the sequence that is the value of `slot`.

```py
import sys
import warnings
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml


def yaml_set_anchor(self, value, always_dump=True):
    self.anchor.value = value
    self.anchor.always_dump = always_dump

ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedBase.yaml_set_anchor = yaml_set_anchor

in_file = Path('file_in.yaml')
   
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    data = yaml.load(in_file)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
components: &base
  type1: 3  # sample comment
  type2: 0x353
  type3: 1.2.3.4
  type4: "bla"
  schemas:
    description: 'ex1' # this is comment
test2:
  <<: *base
  type4: 4555  # under the sea :)

yellow: &yellow
  bla: 1

collor: &yellow
  bla: 2

paint:
  color: *yellow

slot_si_value_t: &bla1
  desc: hav slot 2
  slot_number: 2   #SI_SLOT_2
  inst_max: 4

slot:
- slot_si_value: *bla1
- slot_si_value: &bla2
    desc: hav slot 4
    slot_number: 4 #SI_SLOT_4
    inst_max: 4
```

You should update your input file to dispose, or change, the duplicate keys. Even
then this will not exactly round-trip in `ruamel.yaml` since you have inconsistent
indentation ( e.g. the root level mapping indents two spaces for `components` and
four spaces for `slot_si_value_t` ), and that is being normalized.