# ruamel.yaml deletes unused anchors

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I have the following yaml file:

```
anchors:
  kubernetes:
  - kubelet: &1GiKubeReserved
      kubeReserved:
        cpu: 80m
        memory: 1Gi
        pid: 20k
  - kubelet: &2GiKubeReserved
      kubeReserved:
        cpu: 160m
        memory: 2Gi
        pid: 20k
cluster:
  name: test
  kubernetes:
    kubelet:
      <<: *1GiKubeReserved
```

Loading the above file with ruamel.yaml removes the unused `2GiKubeReserved` anchor.

```
-  - kubelet: &2GiKubeReserved
+  - kubelet:
```

Snippet of the Python code:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
file = 'example.yaml'
with open(file, 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)
    f.seek(0)
    yaml.dump(data, f)
    f.truncate()
```

Is there a way to preserve this kind of unused anhors?

In this case I'm expecting to have no diff.

Answer (score 0):

An anchor is stored on an `Anchor()` instance in the `.anchor` attribute attached to the object.
That `Anchor()` instance, apart from the anchor value, has an attribute `always_dump` that
is set to `False` by default. You can set that during load time (as shown in
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71920424/1307905) answer), or walk recursively
over the datastructure and change that `always_dump` attribute:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
anchors:
  kubernetes:
  - kubelet: &1GiKubeReserved
      kubeReserved:
        cpu: 80m
        memory: 1Gi
        pid: 20k
  - kubelet: &2GiKubeReserved
      kubeReserved:
        cpu: 160m
        memory: 2Gi
        pid: 20k
cluster:
  name: test
  kubernetes:
    kubelet:
      <<: *1GiKubeReserved
"""

def set_all_anchors_to_dump(data):
    if hasattr(data, 'anchor') and not data.anchor.always_dump:
        data.anchor.always_dump = True
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            set_all_anchors_to_dump(v)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for elem in data:
            set_all_anchors_to_dump(elem)
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
# print('>>>', data['anchors']['kubernetes'][1]['kubelet'].anchor.always_dump)
set_all_anchors_to_dump(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
anchors:
  kubernetes:
  - kubelet: &1GiKubeReserved
      kubeReserved:
        cpu: 80m
        memory: 1Gi
        pid: 20k
  - kubelet: &2GiKubeReserved
      kubeReserved:
        cpu: 160m
        memory: 2Gi
        pid: 20k
cluster:
  name: test
  kubernetes:
    kubelet:
      <<: *1GiKubeReserved
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If this resolves your issue, please consider accepting the answer (clicking on the V, to the left of the top of the answer). That shows others your question was resolved (not just here, also in overview lists).